# If possible, how can we avoid re-preparing a statement in pure SQL?

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

While pondering a potential solution to another question on SO, I started considering using a prepared statement within a procedure (no dynamic SQL in functions makes me sad). The naive approach of executing a `PREPARE` in the procedure seems inefficient, as the statement only needs to be prepared the first time the procedure is called during a session. Is it possible in MySQL to prepare a statement only if it doesn't already exist? Is there a way of checking for the existence of a prepared statement?

Here's a sample procedure for people to play with. It creates a statement that `SELECT`s all columns of the given type from the given table.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS select_columns_of_type_statement;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_columns_of_type_statement(IN db VARCHAR(255), IN tbl VARCHAR(255), IN type VARCHAR(255), OUT result VARCHAR(4095))
  READS SQL DATA
  NOT DETERMINISTIC -- as tables can be ALTERed
BEGIN
    SET @scots_db=db, @scots_tbl=tbl, @scots_type=type;
    PREPARE generate_scots FROM "SELECT CONCAT(
          'SELECT ',
          GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', '),
          ' FROM `', ?, '`.`', ?, '` '
          )
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=? AND TABLE_NAME=? AND data_type=?
      INTO @scots_stmt";
    EXECUTE generate_scots USING @scots_db, @scots_tbl, @scots_db, @scots_tbl, @scots_type;
    SET result = @scots_stmt;
END //
delimiter ;
```

Example usage:

```
CALL select_columns_of_type_statement('mysql', 'user', 'int', @stmt);
SELECT @stmt;
-- or even:
SET @stmt=CONCAT(@stmt, 'LIMIT 3');
PREPARE user_int_cols FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE user_int_cols;
```

That user variables must be used so much also makes me sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking existence may not be possible, but the try-and-handle-failure pattern will work. [`DECLARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html) an error handler that defines & executes the prepared statement, and execute the prepared statement outside of the handler. If the statement doesn't exist, the error handler will run. It's not pretty, but it works.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS select_columns_of_type_statement;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE select_columns_of_type_statement(IN db VARCHAR(255), IN tbl VARCHAR(255), IN type VARCHAR(255), OUT result VARCHAR(4095))
  READS SQL DATA
  NOT DETERMINISTIC -- as tables can be ALTERed
BEGIN
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER
      FOR 1243
      BEGIN
        PREPARE generate_scots FROM "SELECT CONCAT(
              'SELECT ',
              GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', '),
              ' FROM `', ?, '`.`', ?, '` '
              )
          FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
          WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=? AND TABLE_NAME=? AND data_type=?
          INTO @scots_stmt";
        EXECUTE generate_scots USING @scots_db, @scots_tbl, @scots_db, @scots_tbl, @scots_type;
      END;
    SET @scots_db=db, @scots_tbl=tbl, @scots_type=type;
    EXECUTE generate_scots USING @scots_db, @scots_tbl, @scots_db, @scots_tbl, @scots_type;
    SET result = @scots_stmt;
END //
delimiter ;
```